# How to save os.listdir output as list

Tags: python

I am trying to save all entries of `os.listdir("./oldcsv")` separately in a list but I don't know how to manipulate the output before it is processed.

What I am trying to do is generate a list containing the absolute pathnames of all *.csv files in a folder, which can later be used to easily manipulate those files' contents. I don't want to put lots of hardcoded pathnames in the script, as it is annoying and hard to read.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("./oldcsv"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        print(os.path.join("/oldcsv", file))
```

Normally I would use a loop with `.append` but in this case I cannot do so, since `os.listdir` just seems to create a "blob" of content. Probably there is an easy solution out there, but my brain won't think of it.

Comment: `os.listdir` returns a list. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `files = os.listdir("./oldcsv")` and then just do whatever with it.

Comment: and i really dont see why you cant use an append here.

Comment: OK this seems like a brainfart on my side. "List" is even in the name. I was just trying to create a new list and put the output of listdir in there with append, which naturally won't work, because I can't append a list as entry of a list. Sorry that I can't give you both a check for "answered question" and I probably need more sleep. Or sugar to get my brain working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module in the standard library that can solve your problem with a single function call:

```py
import glob 

csv_files = glob.glob("./*.csv")  # get all .csv files from the working dir
assert isinstance(csv_files, list)
```

Comment: This is actually 100% what I was looking for. Works perfectly. Great tool, thanks again!